# How to evaluate if <div> is being animated with a custom variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a problem regarding how to evaluate if a  is being animated and blocking a click operator based on this information. I could not use `:animated` as I was using a jQuery plugin for the animation which would break that attribute. Benjamin Powers answered my question by creating a custom attribute and evaluating that instead. ( http://jsfiddle.net/g5mJd/22/ )

However I have been playing around with the code, and I was curious if I could replicate the effect using a variable instead of an attribute. Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/g5mJd/24/

However it seems that this code does not permanently turn my variable `false`:

```
function() {
        $("#block").transition({
            x: '+=100'
        }, 500, function() {
            var anim = false;
    console.log(anim)
        })
```

In the console log it will state that the variable is false, but if I check it again, it become true. What am I doing wrong? (see the jsfiddle for the full code)

EDIT: So I right now this function turn var anim "false" but this instantly changes back to "true", making a button unclickable (The button can only be clicked if anim is "false")

Comment: it seems to be working for me. I click run and it shows "false" in console, After I press run it records "true" for all attempts to click on variable

Comment: The problem is that I intend it to become "false" at the end of the transision. Then the button is clickable again, and during the transision the var is "true" and the button is unclickable. Then at the end it is "false" and I can click on the buttom again.

But what happens is that, like you said, it records "True" at the end of the animation instead of "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `var` in the following line of code:

```
var anim = false;
```

That creates a local variable of the same name and sets it to `false`, it doesn't update the other `anim`. Remove `var`:

```
anim = false;
```

...and it will work as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5mJd/25/

(Do *not* remove `var` from the declaration of `anim` at the top of the code in your fiddle.)

Comment: Thanks so much! I cannot believe I did not figure it out myself

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the :animated selector for jquery also.

```
 $("#block").is(":animated")
```

will do the trick.